# Error 404 page not found when hosting the frontend to the backend through "dist"

Tags: reactjs, express, syntax-error, react-router-dom

I am using the createBrowser of react-router dom. I am trying to host my front end to my backend in nodejs with express but every time I visit another route and refresh the page it says the cannot get the page or error 404(page not found). I have watch tutorial videos how to avoid these but most of them are just creating another jsx component pageNotFound.

I cant see any videos showing creating routes in backend aside from different request.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The basic gist is that your Express server should be configured to return the root `index.html` file ***for all*** page requests into your app. A basic configuration will include something similar to the following route entry.

```js
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

See [Serving Apps with Client-Side Routing](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) for more details.

Any `PageNotFound` component is what is used in the frontend routing when a user has entered a URL path that your app ***doesn't*** explicitly handle, so instead of being served your React app and a blank page, you can provide a "catch-all" route.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

If a user is accessing `"https://yourDomain/foo"` then they will be served your app and the internal routing will not find a match and will render the "catch-all" route and `PageNotFound` component.

Comment: https://codepen.io/WILBERT-RODRIGO-the-sans/pen/wvQLpmm please help . Did I make it correct?

Comment: @WILBERTRODRIGO Looks ok to me. Is that working for you now or have you still an issue?

Comment: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: @WILBERTRODRIGO I see. Unfortunately I'm not well-versed with Express. You may want to edit your post to include your backend Express code, details how you are building and serving the app (*e.g. what CLI commands & scripts, etc*), and any frontend code if that is also relevant.